# Getting "an error occurred while creating the new data source" while creating a new data source in VS2010 from an oracle database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I'm trying to create a data source to fill a datagridview in VS2010.  I'm connected to our database no problem (at least, Test Connection said successful).  When I went to add a data source, it was able to pull all of the tables.  I selected the table I wanted and clicked add, and it's saying `Could not get type information for 'Oven_Schedule_Management.OvenMasterSet'`.  OvenMasterSet is the name that I gave the dataset.  I'm not sure where `Oven_Schedule_Management` is coming from, because it's not a column in this table.

EDIT: I just realized that my application is called `Oven Schedule Management`

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: I posted it above.  `Could not get type information for 'Oven_Schedule_Management.OvenMasterSet`.  One of my coworkers said that the built-in data source stuff in VS doesn't really work with our databases and to hand code them, so I'm going to do it that way

Comment: I recreated my project with a name that does not have an underscore '_' in it.  I was then able to add a datasource.  Very strange...